# Android custom font is created wrong

Tags: android, fonts, textview, typeface

The user can choose between different fonts in my app.

The Typeface is created in this code:

```
public static Typeface getTypeFace(Context context, String assetPath) {
    synchronized (cache) {
        if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
            try {
                Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                        context.getAssets(), assetPath);
                cache.put(assetPath, typeFace);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return cache.get(assetPath);
    }
}
```

The Typeface is created without an error but in Android >5.0 the typeface is simply wrong...

When i use my app with an Android 4.4.2 OS it is created correct.

The font which creates trouble is this one:

http://www.dafont.com/julius-thyssen.font

Any ideas how to handle this?